# npgsql - Does it uses JDBC driver underneath to connect to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Question: 
- Need to connect to Postgresql using Npgsql using multiple connection string?
- How does npgsql connect to Postresql? does it use JDBC dirvers?

Reason: Need for multiple connection string
- For handling failover scenario where Primary DB server goes down and secondary / standby server become primary

Current libraries:
 - Npgsql(3.2.5)
 - Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL (2.0.0)
 - Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design (1.1.1)

Looking forward for alternate approach

Answer (score 2):

Specifying multiple hosts in the connection string isn't currently supported. It is tracked [in this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/732), and there's a high probability we'll do it for the next version. For now you'll have to implement it yourself, by catching connection exceptions from the first attempt and manually trying to connect to the second server.

Other than that, Npgsql is a pure .NET driver that has nothing to do with JDBC.